# Get memory representation of object in dart

Tags: c++, arrays, flutter, dart, pointers

In my project i want to communicate between an Arduino and a phone using the Flutter framework. I created a library for the Arduino part in c++, but I'm struggling to create the same thing in dart.

In the Arduino code I created class, and then used the memory structure of the class, something like this:

```
struct MessageHeaderData {
    unsigned char protocol;
    IP source, destination;
    MessageType messageType;
    unsigned char checksum;
    unsigned short int sizeOfPayload;
    unsigned char numberOfHops;
};

// This is how I get the byte representation in c++
void getMemoryRepresenation(MessageHeaderData data) {
    unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)&value;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(MessageHeaderData); i++) {
        out[i] = buffer[i];
    }
   // Do something with the array
}
```

Can I do something similar in dart?